# With Microsoft Access when doing data-entry can linked fields be matched by partial string?

Tags: microsoft-access

I am trying to improve efficiency of data-entry in access. Imagine this scenario:

- I have two tables (Main, Customer), main has a field imported from Customer (via lookup).
- Main needs to have cust_name filled in, this comes from the customer database.

If you have a customer: Superuser, you can easily type "Super" and see matching entries such as:

Superuser, Superman, Supereasy

But, in another scenario, each customer has a number, like:

AC1/SuperUser
BESuperMan
OISuperEasy

So, when entering data, it becomes complicated because the intellisense does not help. Typing super will not show like-matches because they don't have the same starting data.